# Grouping dynamic data in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, grouping, dynamic-data

I'm attempting to create a highchart populated by dynamic data that looks something similar to the following image:

[image]

Where the y-axis (technically just the x-axis with the `inverted: true` tag) is a list of people grouped by location. However, I'm having trouble displaying the data grouped by their locations with the locations being displayed also. The actual view isn't important, just that it neatly groups the data and displays the location.

All I've managed to do so far is simply *sort* the data and tag the location name to the end of the person, but that's not quite what I want:

[image]

I'm aware that this is a relatively easy thing to do with categories and data series, but the only examples of this i could find didn't involve dynamic data. Here is some of my code so far:

```
         function loadChart() {
            //calculate height based on number of users displayed, and width based on the panel body width
            var chartHeight = users.length * 20 + 75;
            var chartWidth = $('#InOutPanelViewId').width();

            chart = Highcharts.chart('ChartViewId', {
                chart: {
                    width: chartWidth,
                    height: chartHeight,
                    type: 'columnrange',
                    inverted: true,
                    spacingLeft: 0
                },
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                xAxis: {
                    showEmpty: false,
                    title: null,
                    type: 'category',
                    labels: {
                        align: 'right',
                        format: '{value.User}',
                        style: {
                            color: 'black',
                            fontSize: '12pt'
                        }
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    showEmpty: false,
                    title: '',
                    type: 'datetime',
                    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                        second: '%I:%M %P',
                        minute: '%I:%M %P',
                        hour: '%I:%M %P',
                        day: '%I:%M %P',
                        week: '%I:%M %P',
                        month: '%I:%M %P',
                        year: '%I:%M %P'
                    },
                    min: startTime.valueOf(),
                    max: endTime.valueOf(),
                    plotLines: [{
                        color: 'grey',
                        value: time,
                        width: 1.5
                    }]
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                series: [
                    { name: "Data", borderWidth: 0, data: chartData }
                ],
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<b>' + this.point.jobcode + '</b><br>' + this.point.timespan + '<br>';
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Where `chartData` currently looks like this:

```
chartData[chartData.length] = { name: user, low: displayStart.valueOf(), high: displayEnd.valueOf(), timespan: timeSpan, jobcode: value.JobCodeName, color: colour };
```

And is populated with dynamic data it pulls from an endpoint. The endpoint does also send back the location, so I'm wondering how I can use this structure and the location i'm sending back to group the data and display it nicely.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: In case I'm not clear, please ignore the actual data... (even tho it looks different in the 2 images). The only problem I'm having is the grouping of the data

Comment: What is the problem with setting the chart with dynamic data? Cannot you process the data before you put it in the chart config? A live example with some sample data would be very helpful to understand what is your goal.

Comment: The problem is GROUPING the dynamic data and displaying the group categories in the chart (on the y-axis)

Comment: The HighCharts docs provide an example on how to group data at https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped. If you need more help, I recommend starting with this example and a static mock of your data structure and post a link to your JSFiddle here.